The when part is executed, but the answer is: Process finished with exit code 0
Run method:
def create_project(self):
        Logic.start_app()
        time.sleep(5)
        Name.filebut.click_input()
        time.sleep(5)
        Logic.stop_app()

He takes the method:
def start_app(self, app_path):
    app.start(app_path, timeout=10)
    time.sleep(3)
    app.connect(best_match="text", timeout=10)

As a result, the program starts and the response Process finished with exit code 0 immediately appears.
There's no way I can fix this. I am using the pywinauto library.
I expect that the program will start, the necessary button will be pressed and the program will close.

It is still not clear which line of the script fails. Could you please provide full output? Maybe traceback is also printed? Can you add it to your question? And how object Name is created? Maybe by another piece of code?

объект name выглядит вот так:
class Name(object):
filebut = app.top_window().child_window(best_match="Файл")
а весь вывод:
Connected to pydev debugger (build 241.18034.82)
Process finished with exit code 0

app.top_window() is not recommended to use. Because it may catch different window at different moment, and then it will be frozen to this handle even if top window is really changed. Use app.window(title="Real top title") or title_re inside it if regular expression is needed. We can speak Russian here: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pywinauto Though it is monitored less frequently.
